# How to fix "node: command not found" on a Mac? Node was installed using nvm from homebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, nvm

I installed **nvm** on my Mac using Homebrew.

```
brew update
brew install nvm
mkdir ~/.nvm
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Added below to my .bash_profile

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Then in my shell

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $NVM_DIR
```

After doing those steps I **installed** **nodejs** **using** **nvm**

```
nvm install v6.11.2
```

The problem is when I type node it *says node: command not found*

```
$ node
$ -bash: node: command not found
```

How do I make nodejs to work?

Below is my .bash_profile

```
if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

#for brew nvm
exportNVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

This is the list of nodejs according to nvm

```
$ nvm list
        v6.11.2
node -> stable (-> v6.11.2) (default)
stable -> 6.11 (-> v6.11.2) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/boron (-> v6.11.2)
lts/argon -> v4.8.4 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.11.2
```

Comment: Did you try with a new Terminal window? You can also try 'nvm use v6.11.2' after install. Nvm should add node to your path.

Comment: @Mikko This eventually led me to fixing my issue.  I was running 'nvm use v6.11.2 on the terminal and it was not showing any error messages until I closed the terminal (as you have suggested) and ran the 'nvm use v6.11.2' command again.  Then it eventually returned a suggestion to Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v6.11.2` to unset the nvm from '/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.33.2/versions/node/v6.11.2' which eventually resolved my issue.  
You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it as soon as you do.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear, I'll make an answer out of the comment, feel free to edit it if you think you can make it follow your solution better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nvm should add node to your path. Close your terminal and open a new one. Try running node now. If you still have issues run:

`nvm use v6.11.2`

There seems to be an issue with nvm installations with homebrew. The fix is to run:

`nvm use --delete-prefix v6.11.2` (or which ever version you are running)